# Facing some problem while trying to create the query in lambda expression in C# with NEST in elastic search, using Nest 6.0

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

As of now i have Elastic query with json format, now i am trying to convert this query with Nest extension for Asp.Net c# in lambda expression. Facing this problem, any body can help to create the Lambda expression with help of json query.

I have tried, but it's list type inside the query, so while i am trying giving error might be my lambda expression is not correct.

I have tried with this lambda expression, but while i am debugging then query is not creating as like json below, so need your help.

```
 var response = _esclient.EsClient().Search<MyClassname>(a => a
                            .Index
                            .Type
                            .Size
                            .From
                            .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Terms(p => p.Field(ab => ab.model).Terms(searchAjaxRequest.modeltype)),
                                                               m => m.Terms(p => p.Field(ab => ab.variant).Terms(searchAjaxRequest.varientType)),    
                                                           )    )))
```

Just want a Lambda expression in NEST ext. in c# or any tool market which i can use to create the lambda expression with help of json. One more important things over here the bool and must inside the Should will be dynamically increase or decrease.i have no idea how i will handel this situation with the Nest. ideally loop will be use inside should but i am not sure how i will do it.

```
    {  
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
             {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "variant": "lxi"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "model": "ritz"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },              
             {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "variant": "lxi"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "model": "alto"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
             {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "variant": "lxi"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "model": "omni"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "variant": "vxi"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "model": "alto 800"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }       
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facing some problem while trying to create lambda expression in C# with NEST in elastic search, using Nest 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169462/facing-some-problem-while-trying-to-create-lambda-expression-in-c-sharp-with-nes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Fluent DSL lambda expression for below json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232632/how-to-create-fluent-dsl-lambda-expression-for-below-json)

Answer (score 0):

This is fun one :) you should optimize it

```
var client = new InMemoryEsClientFactory(settings).Create();

var searchResponse = client.Search<MyClassname>(s => s.Index("index_name")
    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Bool(b1 =>
        b1.Should(
            should => should.Bool(sb =>
                sb.Must(m3 => m3.Terms(t => t.Field(classname => classname.Model).Terms("eeco")))),
            should => should.Bool(sb =>
                sb.Must(m1 => m1.Term(c => c.Field(classname => classname.Variant).Value("vxi")),
                    m1 => m1.Term(c => c.Field(classname => classname.Model).Value("a star"))))))))));

Request:
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "model": [
                          "eeco"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "variant": {
                          "value": "vxi"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "model": {
                          "value": "a star"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andrey, thanks for replying, i need little bit more help over your answer. if we have multiple bool and must condition inside the Should array and changing the array run time some time we have 2 count some times more. So can you guide how i will create the query in such situation. If you want i have the request json.

Comment: Sure it's possible to change those. Post your example